# Retornar checkbox checado PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo esse código:

```
<?php
    $pdo = db_connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cor_fundo";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $option = "";
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($result as $row) {
          $id = $row['cor_fundo_id'];
          $nome = $row['cor_fundo_nome'];
          $option.='<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="cor_fundo[]" value="'.$id.'">'.$nome.'</label>';
        }
    echo $option;
?>
```

Ele lista os *checkbox's* do banco de dados, mas preciso que ele retorne checado conforme o cliente selecionou.

Obs. Está gravado em array no banco.

Exemplo: 3,4,5

Comment: Já tentou adicionar o `checked` no input? `<input type="checkbox" name="cor_fundo[]" value="'.$id.'" checked>`

Comment: se eu colocar da forma q vc me disse... seleciona todos, e não apenas os q estão no banco

Comment: Como que você salva a opção escolhida pela usuário?

Comment: @DjalmaManfrin gravo em uma coluna como array. Ex. cachorro, gato, coelho = 3,4,5

Comment: Isso não parece fazer muito sentido. Você está selecionando as cores no banco de dados e as listando em forma de `checkbox`. Que coluna seria essa "em forma de array"?

Comment: O teu [MER](http://www.devmedia.com.br/modelo-entidade-relacionamento-mer-e-diagrama-entidade-relacionamento-der/14332) não foi planejado corretamente. Qual a relação das tabelas cliente e cor_fundo?

Comment: Na tabela "cor_fundo" tenho as seguintes colunas: cor_fundo_id e cor_fundo_nome -- faço relação com a tabela "produto" pela seguinte coluna: produto_cor_fundo. --- Qdo vou cadastrar um produto ele lista em checkbox as cores (cor_fundo) que irão aparecer no produto para o cliente comprar. --- O administrador do site selecionas as cores e as elas são gravadas no banco de dados como array (3,4,5)

Comment: Ok e onde está esse valor `produto_cor_fundo` para você saber quais as cores selecionadas? Está em alguma variável que você omitiu na pergunta? Aliás, edite a pergunta e adicione esta explicação do último comentário direto no enunciado. Comentário não deveria ser utilizado para dar informações adicionais. Isso só acontece se a pergunta não está clara o suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

### As tabelas do exemplo

Tabela `cor_fundo`

[image: Tabela cor_fundo]

Tabela `produto`

[image: Tabela produto]

O código está comentado.

```
$pdo = db_connect();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cor_fundo";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//quantidade de cores na tabela cor_fundo
$quant = count($result);

//declaração das variáveis
for ($k = 0; $k <= $quant; $k++) {
    $item = "z".$k;
    $$item = "";
}
$option = "";
$id="";
$produto_cor_fundo="";
$produto_cor_fundo_novo="";
$userSelecionado="";
$userID="";
$usuarioSel="";
$selec="";

// verificação da possibilidade de update
if ((isset($_POST["cor_fundo"]))&&($_POST["userID"]==$_POST["userID_Old"])) {
    //array das cores selecionadas
    $optionArray = $_POST["cor_fundo"];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($optionArray); $i++) {
       $produto_cor_fundo_novo=$produto_cor_fundo_novo.$optionArray[$i].",";
    }

    $produto_cor_fundo_novo = substr($produto_cor_fundo_novo,0,-1);

    //condição para que haja update
    if ($produto_cor_fundo_novo!=$_POST["produto_cor_fundoOld"]){
        $id=$_POST["userID"];
        $sql = "UPDATE produto SET produto_cor_fundo='$produto_cor_fundo_novo' WHERE id='$id'";
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
    }
}

//consulta das cores/usuario selecionado
if (isset($_POST["userID"])) {
    $id=$_POST["userID"];
    $sql = ("SELECT produto_cor_fundo,usuario FROM produto WHERE id = '".$id."'");          

    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();   
    $result2 = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($result2 as $row) {
        $produto_cor_fundo = $row['produto_cor_fundo'];
        $usuarioSel = $row['usuario'];
    }

    $cores = explode(",", $produto_cor_fundo);
    $contad = count($cores);
    $userSelecionado = "Usuario selecionado: ".$usuarioSel;

    //criação das variaveis dinamicas com o atributo checked para os checkbox do usuario
    for ($k = 0; $k < $contad; $k++) {
        $item = "z".$cores[$k];
        $$item = " checked";
    }
}               

$i=1;
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $id = $row['cor_fundo_id'];
    $nome = $row['cor_fundo_nome'];
    if (isset($usuarioSel)) {
        $item = "z".$i;
        $option.='<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="cor_fundo[]" value="'.$id.'" '.$$item.'>'.$nome.'</label>';
    }else{
        $option.='<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="cor_fundo[]" value="'.$id.'">'.$nome.'</label>';
    }
 $i=$i+1;
 }

//construção do select
$sql = ("SELECT id,usuario FROM produto");
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();   
$result3 = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result3 as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $usuario = $row['usuario'];

    if ($usuarioSel==$usuario){
        $selec.="<option value=\"".$id."\" selected>".$usuario."</option>";
    }else{
            $selec.="<option value=\"".$id."\">".$usuario."</option>";
    }
}

echo $userSelecionado;
echo '<br>'; 
echo '<form method="post" action="">'; 
if (isset($_POST["userID"])){
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="userID_Old" value="'.$_POST["userID"].'">'; 
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="produto_cor_fundoOld" value="'.$produto_cor_fundo.'">';
} 
echo "\n"; 
echo $option;
echo "\n";
echo '<br>';
echo '<select name="userID" size="4">';
echo $selec;
echo '</select>';
echo "\n";
echo '<br><button type="submit">Enviar</button>';
echo "\n";
echo '</form>';
```

> Esta solução se baseia em criar variáveis dinâmicas também conhecidas por variáveis variáveis ou ainda variáveis criadas durante a execução no PHP. No loop   `for ($k = 0; $k < $contad; $k++) {` através das variáveis  `$item` criamos as variáveis dinâmicas  `$$item` para cada substring contida no array  `$cores`, que servirão para imprimir o atributo `checked` nas options selecionadas.

Comment: fiquei confuso nesse seu código :D

Comment: Está confuso tudo o que disse: vamos lá. Essa página é de alteração de um produto. Somente o administrador do site tem acesso. Qdo o administrador for alterar o produto tem q aparecer checado ou não a cor de fundo do produto, cadastrado num array a cor que ele cadastrou.

Comment: como o @Leo Caracciolo fez na exibicao das tabelas estão ok são as mesmas tabelas se assim podemos dizer, mas ao inves de pegar pelo usuario irá pegar pelo produto

Answer (score 0):

Caso os checkbox marcados estejam em uma coluna no banco você vai ter que usar o explode.

> Exemplo

```
<?php
    $pdo = db_connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cor_fundo";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $option = "";

    //aqui vc recupera do db o que ele selecionou... (exemplo)
    $usu = $pdo->prepare('SELECT cores_fundo FROM usuario WHERE id=:id_usuario');
    $usu->execute([':id_usuario' => $_SESSION['id_usuario']);
    $usuCor = $usu->fetch();
    $usuCor = explode(",", $usuCor);

    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($result as $row) {
          $id = $row['cor_fundo_id'];
          $nome = $row['cor_fundo_nome'];

          //Verificando se esse ID tá marcado pelo usuario
          $marcado = '';
          if(in_array($id, $usuCor))
                $marcado = 'checked';    

          $option.='<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="cor_fundo[]" value="'.$id.'" '.$marcado.'>'.$nome.'</label>';
        }
    echo $option;
?>
```

> OBS: Os selects na tabela usuário é para recuperar as cores salvas, fiz como exemplo pois não tinha essa informação na pergunta. Mas é só adequar que vai funcionar.

Comment: Você pode me explicar esse $_SESSION['id_usuario'] ?

Comment: Isso é um exemplo de vc pegando o id do usuário logado... não sei se o caso :)

Comment: Entendi, faltam informações na pergunta do Betinho Silva :)

Answer (score 0):

Meu código ficou assim, mas ele não está checando corretamente. Está checando os 2 ultimos apenas, sendo q tem 4 cores

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cor_fundo";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //quantidade de cores na tabela cor_fundo
        $quant = count($result);

        //declaração das variáveis
        for ($k = 0; $k <= $quant; $k++) {
            $item = "z".$k;
            $$item = "";
        }
        $option = "";                                                   

        //consulta das cores/produto selecionado                                                    
        $sql = ("SELECT produto_cor_fundo FROM produto WHERE produto_id = '".$cod."'");          
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();   
        $result2 = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach ($result2 as $row) {
            $produto_cor_fundo = $row['produto_cor_fundo'];                                                     
        }
        $cores = explode(",", $produto_cor_fundo);
        $contad = count($cores);

       //criação das variaveis dinamicas com o atributo checked para os checkbox do produto
        for ($k = 0; $k < $contad; $k++) {
            $item = "z".$cores[$k];
            $$item = " checked";
        }

        $i=1;
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $id = $row['cor_fundo_id'];
            $nome = $row['cor_fundo_nome'];
            if (isset($produto_cor_fundo)) {
                $item = "z".$i;
                $option.='<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="cor_fundo[]" value="'.$id.'" '.$$item.'>'.$nome.'</label>';
            } else {
                $option.='<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="cor_fundo[]" value="'.$id.'">'.$nome.'</label>';
            }
        $i=$i+1;
        }

        echo $option;
        ?>
```